# How to write nodejs service, running all time

Tags: javascript, node.js, service

I am new into nodeJs (and JS), so can you explain me (or give a link) how to write simple service of nodeJs, which run permanently?

I want to write service, which sends a request every second to foreign API at store the results it DB.

So, maybe nodeJs have some simple module to run js method (methods) over and over again?

Or, I just have to write `while` loop and do it there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval()` is what you would use to run something every second in node.js.  This  will call a callback every NN milliseconds where you pass the value of NN.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // execute your request here
}, 1000);
```

If you want this to run forever, you will need to also handle the situation where the remote server you are contacting is off-line or having issues and is not as responsive as normal (for example, it may take more than a second for a troublesome request to timeout or fail).  It might be safer to repeatedly use `setTimeout()` to schedule the next request 1 second after one finishes processing.

```
function runRequest() {
    issueRequest(..., function(err, data) {
        // process request results here

        // schedule next request
        setTimeout(runRequest, 1000);
    })
}

// start the repeated requests
runRequest();
```

In this code block `issueRequest()` is just a placeholder for whatever networking operation you are doing (I personally would probably use the `request()` module and use `request.get()`.

Because your request processing is asynchronous, this will not actually be recursion and will not cause a stack buildup.

---

FYI, a node.js process with an active incoming server or an active timer or an in-process networking operation will not exit (it will keep running) so as long as you always have a timer running or a network request running, your node.js process will keep running.